# window.showModalDialog to jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

we are using showModalDialog on my old application  , I am looking to plan with jquery ui dialog but i have problm to use window.dialogArguments.
here my code with old and new.

**main.html** (old):

```js
function PopUp(page, width, height) {
  var params = [];
  params[0] = window;
  window.showModalDialog(page, params, "'dialogWidth:'+width+'px; dialogHeight:'+height");

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="typet" size="45" readonly="readonly" id="type">
</form>
```

**popup.html**:

```js
function getvalue(value) {
  var params = window.dialogArguments;
  params[0].document.getElementById('FormId').value = value;
  closeWindow();
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="getValue('game video')">game video</li>
</ul>
```

**new_main.html** (new):

```js
function PopUp2(page, Width, Height) {
  var pagetitle = "test";

  var $dialog = jq('<div></div>')
    .load(page)
    .dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      height: Width,
      width: Height,
      title: pagetitle,
      resizable: false
    });

  $dialog.dialog('open');
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="typet" size="45" readonly="readonly" id="type">
</form>
```

How to get value from popup with jQuery dialog when the user clicks a link to input text (on `news_main.html`)?

Comment: Sounds like all you need is to put a form in the new dialog. Is that correct? We have no idea what your old one does

Comment: The concepts are a bit different. The old native modal dialog blocked all the execution untill the dialog was closed. UI dialog is just an element on a page, and the functionality is based on callback function.

Comment: i have updated my code here. 
i would when dialog open, user clik one link. this value will be fill in the main page when popup closed